# Email Saved Search based on conditional field

Tags: email, netsuite, saved-searches

I am looking to send an email from netsuite using the "Recipients from Results"

I already have a saved search that emails based on field "salesrep", however I want to send a 2nd report to "TAMS" (Territory adoption managers) but only if the TAM is not the same as the sales rep. I am not sure if I will need a workflow to do the comparison or if I need to just add a formula.

Any suggestions ??

None

Answer (score 0):

How about a separate saved search that includes all of your original criteria and additional criteria that would leverage a formula field to say sales rep not equal to TAMS and then email the tams from results?

Answer (score 0):

Formula definitely!  `DECODE({salesrep},<Yours TAMS field ID>,'Ignore','Email')`

[image]

Comment: Ty Nathan.. I will give it a try.